# Deploy chef in Container/Kubernetes/Docker

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, chef-infra

How do i install chef/Ansible as a container on kubernetes/docker.
I have checked docker hub registry for chef image.
I have pulled chef/chef and chef/chefdk but none of them is working for me.
I have run the command:
docker run -d -p 443:443 chef/chef

Comment: What do you want it to manage?  Particularly in Kubernetes, this combination of tooling doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: It's not clear that you have tried doing your own research to solve this yet. Both Chef and Ansible are extensively documented online, and you will find both official documentation as well as many blog posts that explore these configuration management systems. Some may even be apropos to your question about Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chef/chef docker container exists mostly for the kitchen-dokken driver, not really independent use. If you want to make a containerized chef solo thingy, Chef Software has some Habitat examples you can follow, or at least they used to.